# Inertia js redirect to laravel blade file properly

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, inertiajs

i using inertiajs in laravel application, my login page build default laravel breeze . when I login dashboard is pop view.

dashboard view page is laravel blade file.

i expect its redirect to dashboard with out pop up view.

Comment: You need to render it using Inertia so it does not pop out

`return Inertia::render('Your/page');`

Comment: Please share code for more context on your goals.

Answer (score 0):

Inertia renders non-inertia responses as a popup since it can't insert it into the vue app as a component, you should either use blade entirely (there is a breeze stack for blade) or use vue component only.

There *is* a way do a full page redirect reload by calling `Inertia::location($dashboardUrl)` instead of `redirect()` but it's meant to for external redirects not within the app.